# Postgres - autovacuum in small tables

Tags: postgresql, performance, autovacuum, postgresql-performance

- What would be a suitable setting for autovacuum to act on this table?

We have a "sequencia" table, it does what the `sequence` of postgres should do, but perhaps by using other DBs the development opted for this approach, which is to use a table in the database to store the last id inserted in other tables.

An example of the table "sequencia":

```
 id_entidade                      no_sequencia    
 -------------------------------  --------------- 
 CLIENTEGESTAO                    33325146        
 VEICULOREVISAO                   14541831        
 DADOSBOOK                        11627492        
 HISTORICOQUILOMETRAGEM           9992701         
 RESULTADOINTEGRACAO              4089476         
 CAMPOSREGISTROINTERFACE          2892807         
 REGISTROINTEGRACAO               1731981         
 ACAO                             1585661         
 ENCAMINHAMENTO                   1263190         
 REQUISICAOOS                     948967          
 MOTIVOEVENTO                     916872          
 EVENTO                           818115          
 VEICULO                          -35041          
 CLIENTE                          -64414
```

The next ID of any record in the database is going to be the "no_sequencia" + 1, so this table receives a high amount of UPDATEs, about 100 per minute and very rarely some INSERT, one per year maybe less, my doubt stays on the autovacuum, today I use the following configuration:

```
`autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor` = 0.20
`autovacuum_vacuum_threshold` = 50
```

When get to 51 updated tuples will clear the table if the autovacuum is available, in a more general context the autovacuum runs every 30 minutes or so if we ignore this table:

```
 relname                    n_live_tup   % live   n_dead_tup    Tamanho     Registros    Configuracao                                                                                                                               last_autovacuum      autovacuum_count  
 -------------------------  -----------  -------  ------------  ----------  -----------  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  -------------------  ------------------
 sequencia                  191          65       99            752 KB      191          {autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0.20,autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=50}                                                                       17/01/2018 19:41:31  13806             
 campanha                   3541         98       67            3400 KB     3821         {autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0.05,autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=100}                                                                      17/01/2018 19:40:49  194               
 sms                        2071256      99       1026          773160 KB   2071070      {autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0,autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=10000,autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor=0,autovacuum_analyze_threshold=20000}  17/01/2018 19:24:31  20                
 campanhaexecucao           1948         96       61            136 KB      1980         {autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0.05,autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=100}                                                                      17/01/2018 19:05:48  10                
 telefonema                 8957384      99       1792          1086424 KB  8957050      {autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0,autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=10000,autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor=0,autovacuum_analyze_threshold=20000}  17/01/2018 18:22:45  17                
 email                      1059515      99       3776          945368 KB   1056970      {autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0,autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=10000,autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor=0,autovacuum_analyze_threshold=20000}  17/01/2018 18:11:53  3                 
 oportunidade               698662       99       317           105992 KB   698440       {autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0,autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=10000,autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor=0,autovacuum_analyze_threshold=20000}  17/01/2018 18:06:54  1                 
 interesse                  698254       99       550           93936 KB    698043       {autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0,autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=10000,autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor=0,autovacuum_analyze_threshold=20000}  17/01/2018 18:06:46  1                 
 encaminhamento             8277408      99       1998          1187264 KB  8277230      {autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0,autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=10000,autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor=0,autovacuum_analyze_threshold=20000}  17/01/2018 18:03:24  39                
 evento                     3689441      99       5672          2376448 KB  3688780      {autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0,autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=10000,autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor=0,autovacuum_analyze_threshold=20000}  17/01/2018 17:06:11  36                
 sessao                     1736         94       102           216 KB      1736         {autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0.05,autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=100}                                                                      17/01/2018 16:22:44  18                
 acao                       14931180     99       6635          4250392 KB  14924700     {autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0,autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=25000,autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor=0,autovacuum_analyze_threshold=50000}  17/01/2018 15:25:32  10                
 parametroempresa           349          81       77            48 KB       348          {autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0.20,autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=50}                                                                       17/01/2018 14:22:41  22                
 tipoevento                 4565         99       19            3656 KB     4565         {autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0.05,autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=100}                                                                      17/01/2018 14:08:40  3                 
 usuariotipoevento          64254        98       992           4544 KB     64270        {autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0.05,autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=100}                                                                      17/01/2018 14:03:41  5                 
 registrointerface          4050719      99       1194          549800 KB   4049100      {autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0,autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=10000,autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor=0,autovacuum_analyze_threshold=20000}  17/01/2018 13:30:35  2                 
 regraleadmontadora         117          90       13            48 KB       117          {autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0.20,autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=50}                                                                       17/01/2018 11:58:37  6                 
 usuarioformacontato        78593        98       1389          5944 KB     79230        {autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0.05,autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=100}                                                                      17/01/2018 11:22:39  3                 
 arquivointegracao          1843         93       134           296 KB      1787         {autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor=0.05,autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=100}                                                                      17/01/2018 02:00:50  12
```

In the above example we saw that `n_dead_tup` has passed 51, the autovacuum is sleeping 60 seconds.

```
 name ---------------------------------- setting ----- unit   
 autovacuum                              on             
 autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor         0.1            
 autovacuum_analyze_threshold            50             
 autovacuum_freeze_max_age               200000000      
 autovacuum_max_workers                  3              
 autovacuum_multixact_freeze_max_age     400000000      
 autovacuum_naptime                      60            s      
 autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay            20            ms     
 autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit            -1             
 autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor          0.2            
 autovacuum_vacuum_threshold             50             
 autovacuum_work_mem                     -1            kB
```

- What would be a suitable setting for autovacuum to act on this table?

The process is working well, this is just a preventive action, if you need more information please inform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing here indicates a need for a change.

Note the [current threshold is not determined](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html) solely by the base threshold, but also by the scale factor.

```
vacuum threshold = vacuum base threshold + vacuum scale factor * number of tuples
```

Which in your case would come to 50 + 0.2 * some unknown number close to 200